# ValueError: Invalid field on model 'res.config.settings' odoo 14

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I'm getting an error issue every time I try to save a setting in my odoo environment:

> ValueError: Invalid field 'expense_extract_show_ocr_option_selection'
> on model 'res.config.settings'

I've been looking a the Odoo base code and I can't find that property, do you know where is it? and more importantly why I'm getting that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the enterprise edition, you have to install HR expense extract

Answer (score 2):

In case someone comes to this question from a similar error:

Just look up the field and install the module where the field is added.
In my example, it was the field `enable_ocn` which is added by module `mail_mobile`.
(wanted to give a more common answer to the problem)

Maybe someone knows where this error has its origin...

Comment: I restored the online version of odoo db into the offline (community) version. All the modules used online were automatically installed offline and I still have a similar error. Any other ideas?